# Does PayPal Standard Support Recurring Payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, nopcommerce, recurring

As mentioned in this link

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing_CommandDriven/merchant/wpstandard/WPStandardFAQsBFTwo-outside#Q15

PayPal Standard supports recurring payments for subscriptions and donations.

I am using nopcommerce and i want to support recurring payment for purchased products, will that be possible or does above answer mean it wont be supported other than subscriptions and donation?

Answer (score 4):

When using Website Payments Standard, there are two different types of payments you can set up and use.  There are subscriptions which allow you to create a profile and bill the buyer on a recurring basis.  With subscriptions, this service is free to use with Website Payment Standard, but keep in mind that the buyer will need to have a PayPal account or create one when they sign up.

The other service is Enhanced Recurring Payments which can be added onto your account.  There is an additional monthy charge for this service.  This service would work similar to subsriptions but you would also be able to set up Automatic Billing and Installment Plan buttons.  Also with Enhanced Recurring Payments your buyer does not have to have a PayPal account.  They can use their credit card directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As mentioned in https://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/workitem/10512
PayPal IPN does not properly support recurring payment. This work item is still on roadmap. So currently, the order/payment status change with the IPN notification if it is a one time charge but not if it’s a recurring payment. I want to implement it so that it also supports for recurring payments. I want to know if this is something not supported from paypal? Will paypal be able to change my order status via IPN if i implement paypal direct method as mentioned in your answer?

Comment: IPN supports recurring payments.  I am not sure to what part of recurring payments that you are saying IPN does not support.  Every time that a recurring payment is charged you will receive an IPN.

Comment: IPN supports recurring payments IF you are using Express Checkout, but not if you are using Payflow.  So it should be OK for this user.

Comment: Hi, Did you managed to add this feature to Paypal Standard plugin of nopCommerce? Can you advise how can we add this too? Or share code. We're using Paypal Standard Plugin of nopCommerce and need to add recurring payment feature to this plugin.